# Svg image shows black in android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I used the svg image and it showed everything correctly
But I do not know why this photo is shown in black on Android
It works properly in iOS

[svg image is shown in black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO7bn.jpg)

Comment: Please post some code where you embed the SVG, the SVG itself and everything useful to identify the issue. Also, are you using React Native?

Comment: @Theraloss I put the SVG code and my own component below
I think this problem is due to SVG codes

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="78.597" height="104.363" viewBox="0 0 78.597 104.363">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
      <rect id="Rectangle_2383" data-name="Rectangle 2383" width="68.887" height="104.363" fill="none"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-3">
      <rect id="Rectangle_2381" data-name="Rectangle 2381" width="68.885" height="104.363" fill="none"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-4">
      <path id="Path_17139" data-name="Path 17139" d="M23.052,19.45c0,.165,0,.343-.014.533L23.023,20c.014-.191.014-.368.029-.546" transform="translate(-23.023 -19.45)" fill="none"/>
    </clipPath>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="-53.033" y1="1176.295" x2="-50.709" y2="1176.295" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f9cfbf"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#e293d3"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-5">
      <path id="Path_17140" data-name="Path 17140" d="M23.1,18.63a.591.591,0,0,1-.014.152v-.14Z" transform="translate(-23.083 -18.63)" fill="none"/>
    </clipPath>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="-191.24" y1="3299.65" x2="-182.936" y2="3299.65" xlink:href="#linear-gradient"/>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-6">
      <path id="Path_17141" data-name="Path 17141" d="M18.771,16.76a.117.117,0,0,1-.058.025l.014-.013c.014,0,.029-.013.043-.013" transform="translate(-18.713 -16.76)" fill="none"/>
    </clipPath>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-3" x1="-812.672" y1="1579.157" x2="-769.263" y2="1579.157" xlink:href="#linear-gradient"/>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-7">
      <path id="Path_17142" data-name="Path 17142" d="M66.514,31.587a6.44,6.44,0,0,0-2.507,1.1c-.014-.8,0-1.778-.072-2.515-.13-1.334-1.087-1.245-1.087-1.245a13.831,13.831,0,0,0-.507,2.413,35.471,35.471,0,0,0-.3,4.572,5.111,5.111,0,0,1-.42,1.969V37.9a1.487,1.487,0,0,0-.275.229c-1.449,1.435-7.276,6.985-7.276,6.985l-2.812-2.489v-.013c.3-.61.493-.953.493-.953s-5.29-7.1-9.189-9.437a40.151,40.151,0,0,0-9.131-3.683,21.8,21.8,0,0,1-.058-3.277v-.013c.014-.191.014-.368.029-.546a1.57,1.57,0,0,0,.014-.254,1.212,1.212,0,0,1,.014-.229V24.2A.845.845,0,0,0,33.44,24c0-.064.014-.127.014-.191v-.14l.014-.013v-.013a15.533,15.533,0,0,0,3.319-7.379c.449.165.783-.622.739-1.08-.029-.483,1.435-1.956.971-2.87a.665.665,0,0,0-.841-.3,7.1,7.1,0,0,0,0-2.731,5.034,5.034,0,0,0-1.406-2.642,5.693,5.693,0,0,0,1.261-4.369,2.851,2.851,0,0,1-2.478,1.905S36.687,1.308,33.194,0c0,0,.913,1.372-1.478,2.121s-7.377-.279-10.551,2.985a5.728,5.728,0,0,0-1.145,2.045c-.681.038-.957.61-1.015,1.867a6.866,6.866,0,0,0,.754,2.934A.881.881,0,0,0,19,12.32c-.58.762-.333,1.5.1,2.337s.913,2.718,1.841,2.121a16.129,16.129,0,0,0,1.217,5,6.634,6.634,0,0,0,1.116,2.045c.014.038.014.076.029.127.058.508.13,1.156.188,1.829.145,1.473.261,3.124.3,3.836,0,0-5.319,2.731-8.928,4.991s-7.2,13.361-7.2,13.361a4.258,4.258,0,0,0,.435.432l-.043-.025s-.13.47-.319,1.168a3.7,3.7,0,0,0-.1.381c-.043.127-.072.267-.116.406-.565,2.172-1.333,5.487-.986,6.325.478,1.092,6.058,5.055,9.624,7.354-.2,1.372-.362,2.286-.391,2.413v.013c-1.507,2.413-4.189,9.462-1.29,11.393a5.8,5.8,0,0,0,2.942.61.746.746,0,0,1-.116.013,23.318,23.318,0,0,0,2.739-.089c.014.165.2,1.854.42,3.95a.31.31,0,0,1,.014.114q.022.152.043.5.022.171.043.381c.014.178.029.368.058.584,0,.127.014.267.029.406.014.089.014.191.029.292a81.577,81.577,0,0,1,.145,11.532,60.435,60.435,0,0,0-15.435.2l-.014.229-.014-.013a13.618,13.618,0,0,0-3.131-1.016s-2.551,7.176-2.2,8.129h2.2s-.043-.572-1.029-1.13S3.6,99.117,5.149,99h.014l-.043.419c13.638,2.146,16.9,5.233,21.856,4.1,4.8-1.092,4.638-20.6,4.623-21.884.188,1.689.406,3.455.652,4.75.652,3.455,1.174,15.584,1.174,15.584.188-.064.391-.127.594-.178a8.909,8.909,0,0,0-1.044,2.566H44.194s-.319-.711-2.044-1.118-4.8-1.384-5.029-1.918c.377-.025.594-.025.594-.025s7.348-35.219,1.275-35.842c-.275-.025-.565-.038-.87-.051a8.155,8.155,0,0,1,.029-1.257c.2-2.9,1.246-7.341,1.42-8.649.232-1.626,2.362-5.868,2.362-5.868L47.629,53c.029-.191.087-.533.13-.826a.97.97,0,0,1,.043-.216,2.174,2.174,0,0,1,.043-.241.507.507,0,0,0,.014-.1c.029-.114.043-.216.072-.33l.319.165.841.419h.014c1.609.749,4.435,1.842,5.623.9,1.725-1.359,9.058-10.389,10.145-13.374a2.067,2.067,0,0,0,.072-.241c.638-.038,1.42-.927,2.3-1.562,1.232-.9,1.058-2.146,1.507-3.988s-.246-2.439-2.246-2.019m-49.7,27.32a15.5,15.5,0,0,1-1.58-1.664l-1.565-2.019.7-1.334.652-1.27c.42.178.667.267.667.267L17.092,49.2a45,45,0,0,1-.275,9.7" transform="translate(-0.001)" fill="none"/>
    </clipPath>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-4" x1="0.223" y1="1.256" x2="0.235" y2="1.256" xlink:href="#linear-gradient"/>
  </defs>
  <g id="Group_3901" data-name="Group 3901" transform="translate(-32.046 -649.389)">
    <g id="Group_3825" data-name="Group 3825" transform="translate(32.046 649.389)">
      <g id="Group_3824" data-name="Group 3824" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
        <g id="Group_3823" data-name="Group 3823">
          <g id="Group_3822" data-name="Group 3822" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
            <path id="Path_17099" data-name="Path 17099" d="M5.375,76.221a13.523,13.523,0,0,0-3.138-1.01S-.307,82.379.032,83.331H2.238S2.2,82.758,1.219,82.2,3.6,78.8,5.159,78.686s.216-2.465.216-2.465" transform="translate(0 20.313)" fill="#2a2220"/>
            <path id="Path_17100" data-name="Path 17100" d="M23.8,80.337a9.078,9.078,0,0,0-1.045,2.568H33.975s-.317-.714-2.036-1.11-4.81-1.383-5.031-1.92-2.746-.8-3.112.462" transform="translate(10.223 21.453)" fill="#2a2220"/>
            <path id="Path_17101" data-name="Path 17101" d="M30.012,65.69s.335,20.814-4.62,21.943-8.213-1.962-21.857-4.1l.271-3.094a60.7,60.7,0,0,1,15.443-.208A37.928,37.928,0,0,0,19.485,73c-.271-3.688-1.02-10.548-1.02-10.548l12.221-3.615Z" transform="translate(1.588 15.892)" fill="#553772"/>
            <path id="Path_17102" data-name="Path 17102" d="M14.489,78.613s1.968.447,2.851.714a5.075,5.075,0,0,1-1.8-3.39c-.271-2.29-.935-8.953-1.417-11.123a86.339,86.339,0,0,1,.365,13.8" transform="translate(6.346 17.505)" fill="#514237"/>
            <path id="Path_17103" data-name="Path 17103" d="M12.48,50.778l1.086,4.214,4.209,2.469,9.3-4.314-2.964-3.32Z" transform="translate(5.607 13.457)" fill="#604d3f"/>
            <path id="Path_17104" data-name="Path 17104" d="M33.241,43.391s5.081,2.835,6.8,1.487,9.051-10.391,10.137-13.365-2.083-2.7-3.531-1.269-7.284,6.98-7.284,6.98l-2.8-2.5s-5.549,5.521-3.319,8.67" transform="translate(14.699 7.888)" fill="#fecc9b"/>
            <path id="Path_17105" data-name="Path 17105" d="M39.2,36.051l-2.1,1.993s1.086-1.189.815-1.993-1.8-1.04-2.274.565-2.032,5.9-1.383,6.194l-1.177-.592s.515-7.1,3.319-8.671Z" transform="translate(14.862 9.061)" fill="#f6b07f"/>
            <path id="Path_17106" data-name="Path 17106" d="M42.516,31.741a5.059,5.059,0,0,0,.419-1.972,34.6,34.6,0,0,1,.306-4.579,13.842,13.842,0,0,1,.509-2.411s.951-.089,1.087,1.25,0,3.48.236,3.9,2.47,2.3.794,5.045-3.351-1.229-3.351-1.229" transform="translate(19.104 6.152)" fill="#fecc9b"/>
            <path id="Path_17107" data-name="Path 17107" d="M43.834,26.527a6.04,6.04,0,0,1,3.089-1.636c2-.415,2.681.179,2.241,2.023s-.272,3.093-1.494,3.984-2.239,2.232-2.987,1.219-1.442-5.071-.848-5.591" transform="translate(19.596 6.689)" fill="#ffdbbb"/>
            <path id="Path_17108" data-name="Path 17108" d="M31.053,22.467a40.32,40.32,0,0,1,9.135,3.69c3.891,2.338,9.186,9.437,9.186,9.437s-3.529,6.385-4.118,11.343l-5.7-3.372s-2.128,4.243-2.354,5.869S35.392,57.642,35.8,59.9c0,0-12.127,1.624-22.082,0,0,0,1.9-10.669,1-16.775l-1.4,3.688S7.968,44.833,5.3,41.9c0,0,3.575-11.1,7.194-13.365s8.935-4.989,8.935-4.989Z" transform="translate(2.381 6.068)" fill="#953478"/>
            <path id="Path_17109" data-name="Path 17109" d="M28.934,41.166s2.693-5.591,1.2-9.815a31.373,31.373,0,0,1,1.017,6.206c.091,2.855,3.716,5.586,3.716,5.586s-.175,1.017-.23,1.395Z" transform="translate(13.001 8.467)" fill="#74245c"/>
            <path id="Path_17110" data-name="Path 17110" d="M12.2,39.661s-.532-3.46-.735-4.353a15.932,15.932,0,0,1,2.512,6.068c.3,2.884-1.294,14.4,19.28,13.239a6.973,6.973,0,0,0,.03,1.82s-12.277,2.083-22.4.466c0,0,2.084-11.967,1.315-17.241" transform="translate(4.891 9.536)" fill="#74245c"/>
            <path id="Path_17111" data-name="Path 17111" d="M14.707,9.639s-.894-.613-1.483.141-.342,1.491.1,2.334.907,2.743,1.846,2.117-.465-4.593-.465-4.593" transform="translate(5.786 2.54)" fill="#fecc9b"/>
            <path id="Path_17112" data-name="Path 17112" d="M25.278,10.034s1.461-1.166,1.923-.259-1,2.383-.962,2.869-.332,1.36-.832,1.036-.129-3.646-.129-3.646" transform="translate(11.299 2.547)" fill="#fecc9b"/>
            <path id="Path_17113" data-name="Path 17113" d="M26.73,12.554s1.233-1.373.716-4.332-3.773-4.288-3.773-4.288l-.925,2.138Z" transform="translate(10.222 1.063)" fill="#604d3f"/>
            <path id="Path_17114" data-name="Path 17114" d="M26.307,18.536a29.11,29.11,0,0,0,0,5.549c.339,1.487-1.674,3.272-4.887,3.331a5.814,5.814,0,0,1-4.774-2.22s-.332-5.289-.641-6.768,10.3.108,10.3.108" transform="translate(7.189 4.807)" fill="#fecc9b"/>
            <path id="Path_17115" data-name="Path 17115" d="M20.927,23.177a9.761,9.761,0,0,0,5.265-2.75c.045-1.052.114-1.89.114-1.89s-10.612-1.589-10.3-.108c.107.514.217,1.492.316,2.547,1.468,1.039,2.375,2.439,4.606,2.2" transform="translate(7.189 4.807)" fill="#f6b07f"/>
            <path id="Path_17116" data-name="Path 17116" d="M6.071,38.087S4,45.1,4.545,46.365s8.055,6.462,11.222,8.366a64.11,64.11,0,0,0,5.884,3.133l1.288-2.1s-8.145-6.781-9.706-8.8l-1.561-2.022,1.351-2.6Z" transform="translate(2.001 10.287)" fill="#fecc9b"/>
            <path id="Path_17117" data-name="Path 17117" d="M12.032,43.6l.659-1.269L5.739,38.086s-.243.828-.542,1.965c1.53,2.014,4.294,2.8,6.835,3.551" transform="translate(2.335 10.286)" fill="#f6b07f"/>
            <path id="Path_17118" data-name="Path 17118" d="M16.32,54.19s.2.555,1.019.338,5.371-1.946,6.757-2.248c0,0-.468-.885-2.345-.469a17.582,17.582,0,0,1-4.141.277Z" transform="translate(7.333 13.963)" fill="#fecc9b"/>
            <path id="Path_17119" data-name="Path 17119" d="M15.7,20.526a6.494,6.494,0,0,0,6.312,4.45c5.031,0,8.186-6.871,8.432-10.977s-.493-9.42-6.558-9.333-8.777.95-8.974,3.2-1.381,7.607.788,12.663" transform="translate(6.474 1.26)" fill="#fecc9b"/>
            <path id="Path_17120" data-name="Path 17120" d="M16.473,6.785a8.725,8.725,0,0,1-.468,3.975c-.765,1.9.32,4.495-.345,4.905S15.043,13.311,14.6,12.1,13.046,9.14,13.121,7.5s.52-2.1,1.7-1.795,1.612.652,1.651,1.081" transform="translate(5.894 1.517)" fill="#604d3f"/>
            <path id="Path_17121" data-name="Path 17121" d="M15.246,7.739A19.832,19.832,0,0,0,24.592,9.23c5.518-.389,7.118-4.6,6.718-6.958a2.868,2.868,0,0,1-2.487,1.9S30.481,1.3,26.994,0c0,0,.915,1.362-1.486,2.119S18.133,1.84,14.96,5.1c0,0-1.345,1.642-1.116,2.247a3.926,3.926,0,0,1,1.4.389" transform="translate(6.209 0.001)" fill="#604d3f"/>
            <path id="Path_17122" data-name="Path 17122" d="M16.79,9.806A8.44,8.44,0,0,1,20.1,9.58a.521.521,0,0,0,.59-.359l.171-.716a.474.474,0,0,0-.5-.549A7.392,7.392,0,0,0,16.326,9c-.48.3-.106.96.464.807" transform="translate(7.237 2.148)" fill="#604d3f"/>
            <path id="Path_17123" data-name="Path 17123" d="M25.441,9.882A7.642,7.642,0,0,0,22.4,9.689a.48.48,0,0,1-.542-.331L21.7,8.695a.438.438,0,0,1,.457-.509,6.733,6.733,0,0,1,3.706.947c.441.281.1.888-.422.749" transform="translate(9.746 2.21)" fill="#604d3f"/>
            <path id="Path_17124" data-name="Path 17124" d="M19.017,16.74a21.282,21.282,0,0,0,4.1-.048c.275-.032.491.208.381.433a3.319,3.319,0,0,1-2.757,2.112,2.21,2.21,0,0,1-2.115-2.144.338.338,0,0,1,.393-.353" transform="translate(8.367 4.507)" fill="#433029"/>
            <path id="Path_17125" data-name="Path 17125" d="M22.857,16.714a1.914,1.914,0,0,1-1.678,1.259,7.264,7.264,0,0,1-2.378-.225s-.48-.776-.007-.961,1.123.22,4.064-.072" transform="translate(8.351 4.514)" fill="#fff"/>
            <path id="Path_17126" data-name="Path 17126" d="M20.215,15.379c-.668.027-.515.359.225.384s2.728-.93,1.377-.735a6.9,6.9,0,0,1-1.6.352" transform="translate(8.892 4.052)" fill="#f6b07f"/>
            <path id="Path_17127" data-name="Path 17127" d="M18.235,10.69c-.762.023-1.346.935-1.3,2.04s.693,1.983,1.454,1.961,1.346-.935,1.3-2.04S19,10.667,18.235,10.69" transform="translate(7.606 2.887)" fill="#433029"/>
            <path id="Path_17128" data-name="Path 17128" d="M23.463,10.518c-.762.023-1.346.935-1.3,2.04s.693,1.983,1.454,1.961,1.346-.935,1.3-2.04-.693-1.984-1.454-1.961" transform="translate(9.956 2.841)" fill="#433029"/>
            <path id="Path_17129" data-name="Path 17129" d="M17.484,13.769a2.633,2.633,0,0,1-.268-.017,1.254,1.254,0,0,0,1.039.625c.762-.022,1.346-.935,1.3-2.04a2.774,2.774,0,0,0-.064-.488,1.891,1.891,0,0,1-2.012,1.919" transform="translate(7.736 3.201)" fill="#2b1f1b"/>
            <path id="Path_17130" data-name="Path 17130" d="M22.6,13.69c-.062,0-.116-.009-.175-.011a1.276,1.276,0,0,0,1.065.669c.762-.023,1.345-.936,1.3-2.041a2.65,2.65,0,0,0-.3-1.153A1.882,1.882,0,0,1,22.6,13.69" transform="translate(10.077 3.013)" fill="#2b1f1b"/>
            <path id="Path_17131" data-name="Path 17131" d="M17.32,11.6c-.241.394-.275.786-.08.878s.549-.152.79-.545.275-.786.078-.879-.549.152-.788.546" transform="translate(7.69 2.981)" fill="#fff"/>
            <path id="Path_17132" data-name="Path 17132" d="M17.991,11.111a.894.894,0,0,1-.1.7c-.213.391.216.373.341-.065s-.364-.9-.241-.631" transform="translate(8.013 2.98)" fill="#fff"/>
            <path id="Path_17133" data-name="Path 17133" d="M22.573,11.428c-.241.394-.275.786-.08.878s.549-.152.79-.545.275-.786.078-.879-.549.152-.788.546" transform="translate(10.05 2.934)" fill="#fff"/>
            <path id="Path_17134" data-name="Path 17134" d="M23.244,10.939a.886.886,0,0,1-.1.7c-.213.39.216.372.341-.065s-.364-.9-.241-.631" transform="translate(10.373 2.933)" fill="#fff"/>
            <path id="Path_17135" data-name="Path 17135" d="M34.9,51.551C28.826,50.926,19.018,55,19.018,55a10.394,10.394,0,0,0-2.741-1.974c-1.158-.017-3.332-.653-4.49-.655C10.312,54.6,7.426,61.943,10.4,63.919c3.122,2.079,16.63-1.661,16.63-1.661s.475,6.782,1.136,10.231,1.173,15.585,1.173,15.585a15.274,15.274,0,0,1,4.3-.673S40.977,52.174,34.9,51.551" transform="translate(4.092 13.906)" fill="#553772"/>
            <path id="Path_17136" data-name="Path 17136" d="M25.751,61.062a18.716,18.716,0,0,1,.9-5.155,22.43,22.43,0,0,1-8.28,5.79c-4.66,1.612-6.426,1.65-6.426,1.65s5.2.254,13.8-2.285" transform="translate(5.369 15.1)" fill="#472e5f"/>
            <path id="Path_17137" data-name="Path 17137" d="M26.574,26.449a22.842,22.842,0,0,1-.493,3.721,32.534,32.534,0,0,1-.986,3.645c-.391,1.193-.826,2.388-1.319,3.556l-.232.559-.391-.484a29.005,29.005,0,0,1-2.261-3.175c-.652-1.1-1.275-2.223-1.812-3.364a47.084,47.084,0,0,1-2.638-7.049c.957,2.324,1.986,4.623,3.16,6.846a34.748,34.748,0,0,0,3.725,5.879,45.124,45.124,0,0,0,2.2-6.5,22.469,22.469,0,0,0,.681-3.645,6.446,6.446,0,0,0,.072-.913,6.674,6.674,0,0,0,.029-.927,13.024,13.024,0,0,0-.2-1.842l.246.9c.072.3.1.622.145.926a6.728,6.728,0,0,1,.058.941,6.6,6.6,0,0,1,.014.927" transform="translate(7.388 6.145)" fill="#433029"/>
            <path id="Path_17138" data-name="Path 17138" d="M19.653,38.157l.735.126s.645-1.773,1.273-1.833h.009a1.675,1.675,0,0,0,.486.019A1.479,1.479,0,0,0,23.594,34.9a1.586,1.586,0,0,0-1.788-1.264,1.513,1.513,0,0,0-1.439,1.345l0,.009Z" transform="translate(8.831 9.083)" fill="#f8e4ef"/>
            <g id="Group_3821" data-name="Group 3821" transform="translate(0.001)" style="mix-blend-mode: color-burn;isolation: isolate">
              <g id="Group_3820" data-name="Group 3820">
                <g id="Group_3819" data-name="Group 3819" clip-path="url(#clip-path-3)">
                  <g id="Group_3810" data-name="Group 3810" transform="translate(33.367 24.703)">
                    <g id="Group_3809" data-name="Group 3809" clip-path="url(#clip-path-4)">
                      <path id="Path_17410" data-name="Path 17410" d="M0,0,.547.006V.083L0,.077Z" transform="translate(-0.048 0.543) rotate(-85.569)" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                  <g id="Group_3812" data-name="Group 3812" transform="translate(33.454 23.662)">
                    <g id="Group_3811" data-name="Group 3811" clip-path="url(#clip-path-5)">
                      <path id="Path_17411" data-name="Path 17411" d="M0,0,.153,0V.03L0,.028Z" transform="matrix(0.077, -0.997, 0.997, 0.077, -0.013, 0.152)" fill="url(#linear-gradient-2)"/>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                  <g id="Group_3814" data-name="Group 3814" transform="translate(27.121 21.287)">
                    <g id="Group_3813" data-name="Group 3813" clip-path="url(#clip-path-6)">
                      <path id="Path_17412" data-name="Path 17412" d="M0,0H.029V.06H0Z" transform="translate(-0.002 0.025) rotate(-85.569)" fill="url(#linear-gradient-3)"/>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                  <g id="Group_3816" data-name="Group 3816" transform="translate(0)">
                    <g id="Group_3815" data-name="Group 3815" clip-path="url(#clip-path-7)">
                      <path id="Path_17413" data-name="Path 17413" d="M0,0,140.166,1.522l.748,78.471L.748,78.471Z" transform="translate(-12.247 134.938) rotate(-85.569)" fill="url(#linear-gradient-4)"/>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                  <g id="Group_3818" data-name="Group 3818" transform="translate(27.121 21.287)">
                    <g id="Group_3817" data-name="Group 3817" clip-path="url(#clip-path-6)">
                      <path id="Path_17414" data-name="Path 17414" d="M0,0H.029V.06H0Z" transform="translate(-0.002 0.025) rotate(-85.569)" fill="url(#linear-gradient-3)"/>
                    </g>
                  </g>
                </g>
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <path id="Path_17144" data-name="Path 17144" d="M5.856,0,.785,10.418l2.764.012L0,17.948,9.51,7.118l-2.891.168L12.5,0Z" transform="translate(84 659.356)" fill="rgba(180,109,159,0.61)"/>
    <path id="Path_17145" data-name="Path 17145" d="M0,12.294H5.211L2.254,20.442,11.421,8.686H6.21L8.509,0Z" transform="translate(99.222 683.862)" fill="#cd9dbd"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

AttentionBoySVG is svg image that I said

```
const MyProgress = (props: Props) => {
  const { containerView, commonHeader, prymaryTitleText, progressView, progressFlatList, attentionBoySvg } = styles
  const { renderProgress, OffersPart } = useComponent()
  return (
    <View style={containerView}>
      <PrymaryHeader titleStyle={prymaryTitleText} title={strings.myProgress}>
        <CommonHeader style={commonHeader} headerType='myExercise' />
      </PrymaryHeader>
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={progressView}>
          <FlatList
            style={progressFlatList}
            data={myProgress}
            renderItem={renderProgress}
          />
        </View>
        <OffersPart />
        <AttentionBoySVG
          style={{
            width: 78.6,
            height: 104.36,
            marginTop: -51.1,
            marginLeft: (windowW - ms(320)) / 2,
            marginBottom: 7.2,
          }} />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: You should add your code by editing your post, not as an answer.